# discord.py использую tree.command но бот не регистрирует команды. ошибок нет

Tags: discord.py, discord

У меня бот не регистрирует команды. При запуске бота ошибок не наблюдается, но при этом слеш команда не появляется на сервере(мне нужно чтобы бот работал на многих серверах, а не на одном и по этому писать id сервера не хочу)

````
import discord

import requests
import api

from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord import app_commands
from discord.utils import get


token=api.ip

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot( command_prefix='/',sync_commands_debug=True,sync_commands =True, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing,name="В разработке"),intents= discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot Name: {bot.user}')
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f'Добавленно {len(synced)} команд')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

##########################################
# /kick - выгнать пользователя с сервера #
##########################################

@bot.tree.command(name="kick",description="Выгнать пользователя с сервера")
@app_commands.describe(name_user= "Имя пользователя" ,cause = "Описание причины кика")
async def kick(interaction:discord.Interaction, name_user: str, cause: str):
    await bot.kick(name_user)
    await channel.send("""Пользователь: """+name_user+ """ был выгнан с сервера.
    Причина: """ +cause)

bot.run(token)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Замени @bot.tree на @slash.slash

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext

import requests
import api

from discord.ext import tasks
from discord import app_commands
from discord.utils import get


token=api.ip


bot = commands.Bot( 
    command_prefix='/',
    sync_commands_debug=True,
    sync_commands=True, 
    activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="В разработке"),
    intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)  # Используйте discord_slash для регистрации слеш-команд

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot Name: {bot.user}')
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f'Добавленно {len(synced)} команд')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

##########################################
# /kick - выгнать пользователя с сервера #
##########################################

@slash.slash(name="kick",description="Выгнать пользователя с сервера")
@app_commands.describe(name_user= "Имя пользователя" ,cause = "Описание причины кика")
async def kick(interaction:discord.Interaction, name_user: str, cause: str):
    await bot.kick(name_user)
    await channel.send("""Пользователь: """+name_user+ """ был выгнан с сервера.
    Причина: """ +cause)

bot.run(token)```
````

> Убедитесь, что переменная `api.ip` содержит ваш токен.
> И
> не забудь строчку -

> slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)

Comment: смог сам найти ошибку. но спасибо за помощь. Были проблемы с моей стороны.